# Replace all column values with other values in the same column according to primary key

Tags: sql-server, query, syntax, replace

I'm querying the following table:

| id | value | applicable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 5 | Unknown |
| id1 | 5 | Unknown |
| id1 | 6 | Yes |
| id 2 | 5 | Unknown |
| id 2 | 5 | No |
| id 2 | 3 | Unknown |

I would like to replace all "Unknowns" in the applicable column, with the non-unknown values pertaining to each id.

Ideally, I would like to see this:

| id | value | applicable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 5 | Yes |
| id1 | 5 | yes |
| id1 | 6 | Yes |
| id 2 | 5 | No |
| id 2 | 5 | No |
| id 2 | 3 | No |

Sorry if this a very easy question, I'm new to this!

Thank you

Comment: what haooens if yiou have yes nnd no?

Comment: To add on to nbk's question, which value do you expect to see when you have the same `id` three times, once with the `unknown` value for the `applicable` column, once with `yes`, and once with `no`?

Comment: That wouldn't be possible in my table because one id can only have yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

This expects one one value besides of unknown, if this si not the case you must choose another aggregation function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     ([id] varchar(4), [value] int, [applicable] varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     ([id], [value], [applicable])
> VALUES
>     ('id1', 5, 'Unknown'),
>     ('id1', 5, 'Unknown'),
>     ('id1', 6, 'Yes'),
>     ('id 2', 5, 'Unknown'),
>     ('id 2', 5, 'No'),
>     ('id 2', 3, 'Unknown')
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1
> SET    table1.[applicable]  = t1.[applicable] 
> FROM   table1
>        INNER JOIN (SELECT [id],MIN([applicable]) as [applicable] FROM table1  WHERE  [applicable] <> 'Unknown' GROUP BY [id]) t1
>          ON table1.id = t1.id
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM    table1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id   | value | applicable
> :--- | ----: | :---------
> id1  |     5 | Yes       
> id1  |     5 | Yes       
> id1  |     6 | Yes       
> id 2 |     5 | No        
> id 2 |     5 | No        
> id 2 |     3 | No
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff75ca1f41ed6f2347f3e72fa4e22bc6)*